# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'MutableRefObject<string | null>' and 'string' have no overlap. TS2367

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a problem
Using React and TS

I have state of the email and password in States

```
const emailRef = useRef<string | null>(null);
const passwordRef = useRef<string | null>(null);
```

Setting them like this:

```
const onEmailChange = (value: any) => {
        emailRef.current = value;
    };

    const onPasswordChange = (value: any) => {
        passwordRef.current = value;
    };
```

And try to use them onButtonEnter function butt get this issue:

```
const onButtonEnter = () => {
        if (!buttonDisabled) {
            setButtonDisabled(true);
            if (emailRef === '' && passwordRef === '') { - here I have an issue
                showAlert(errors.invalid);
```

!!! This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'MutableRefObject<string | null>' and 'string' have no overlap.  TS2367

What it can be?

Comment: You are comparing a reference to a DOM element with a string, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your issue is in the error message:

- `emailRef` is a react object - '`MutableRefObject<string | null>`'
- `emailRef.current` is your string

`emailRef` will never be `''`, `emailRef.current` on the other hand might very well be.

Change

```
if (emailRef === '' && passwordRef === '') {
```

into

```
if (emailRef.current === '' && passwordRef.current === '') {
```

And maybe, read up a little bit more on `useRef` in React docs.